# How do I Split the genre, Remove duplicates, and then apply Groupby using Python?

Tags: python, arrays, filter, group-by

```
f = pd.DataFrame({'Movie': ['name1','name2','name3']
                  'genre': [['comedy', 'action'];['comedy','scifi'];['thriller','action']]
                  'distributor': ['disney', 'disney','parmount'})
```

What if the genre has multiple values in it now. The name is both part of **genre[0]** and **genre[1]** if I used groupby.

```
res = f[f['distributor'] == 'disney'].groupby(['genre'])
```

The **genre name1** and **genre name2** will be shown in different rows **g**, but they do have a common genre **comedy**. How do I split the genre, remove duplicates, and then apply groupby.

Comment: Do you really want to remove duplicates genre ? Seems to me in your case you need to split each genre, which means your dataframe will have 6 rows (with a duplicate of each movie). But at least when grouping by genre, comedy will correctly group movies 1 and 2

Comment: yeah i also wnat to know how can i split the genre and use that output which shows in terminal without actually saving it into a column

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you want:

```
>>> f[f["distributor"].eq("disney")].explode("genre").groupby("genre")["Movie"].agg(list)
genre
action           [name1]
comedy    [name1, name2]
scifi            [name2]
Name: Movie, dtype: object
```

Comment: this is what i m looking for can u explain what does explode do

Comment: See the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html). Breaks a list into individual rows.

Comment: i tried the code it still is unpacked the output looks something like this  ['Action', 'Adventure', 'Animation', 'Comedy', 'Family', 'Fantasy', 'Sci-Fi']                                     [G-Force (2009)] need to further split it it seems

Comment: What is your expected output? With the sample you provided in your post, I get the output in my answer. If it doesn't work for you, provide a more representative sample in your question.

Comment: and to count it if i wnat to plot a piechart

Comment: Please don't ask follow-up questions in the comments. This answered your original question. Any new question, create a new post.

Comment: the sample i provided is fine its just the arrays inside genre are bigger eg this is one of the genres first row ['Action', 'Adventure', 'Animation', 'Comedy', 'Family', 'Sci-Fi'] and so by the code u provided its not splitting the rows but just matching the movie with the whole row eg avatar [action,advebtrure,thriller,scifi]

Comment: Provide a better sample then - one where my answer doesn't work. This answer should work regardless of the size of your list